# Java swing how to set application background dynamically

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, background

I would like to know normally how they let a user choose the background color? For example, user chooses the background color to be red color, next time when the user runs the application again the background color will automatically become red color instead of the default color. Do they store the value in the database, so next time user runs the application will first retrieve from the database?

Comment: Hardly any apps allow the specification of background colour. I'd concentrate on the more important areas of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java [`Preferences`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) works for this pretty well.

Edit: I can't remember which one I used, but [this one](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPreferences/article.html) looks OK. Just use `putInt("background", value)`. I'd get the value from `getRGB()`, like they say to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394388).

Comment: It's pretty old, so there's lots of examples. I put one in the answer.