# Reading a color - method to decode it

Tags: java, colors

I save a color in a file by using PrintWriter. The color looks like this and it's a String: `java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]`. 
Now I want to use Scanner, and decode this String to a normal color. As an attempt, I tried

```
layer.shapeColor = Color.decode("java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]");
```

but it doesn't work. What is the method, which changes this kind of String to a color? Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - How to convert a Color.toString() into a Color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394388/java-how-to-convert-a-color-tostring-into-a-color)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a "rgb (x, x, x)" String Into a Color Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613996/parsing-a-rgb-x-x-x-string-into-a-color-object)

Comment: Please show some effort in searching for similar problems before posting a new question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little too late for your project but, if you like regular expressions, there are some implementations you can try:

### Using `Scanner`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UsingScanner {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        
        //Generate random color components:
        final Random rand = new Random();
        final byte[] components = new byte[3];
        rand.nextBytes(components);
        
        //Construct random color:
        final Color original = new Color(components[0] & 0xFF, components[1] & 0xFF, components[2] & 0xFF);
        
        //Debug:
        final String originalToString = original.toString();
        System.out.println(originalToString);
        
        //Scan:
        final Scanner scan = new Scanner(originalToString);
        scan.useDelimiter("(r|\\,g|\\,b)=|\\]").next(); //Use proper delimiter and ignore first part (which is the class name)
        final int r, g, b;
        System.out.println(r = scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println(g = scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println(b = scan.nextInt());
        
        //Verify:
        System.out.println(new Color(r, g, b).equals(original));
    }
}
```

### Using `Pattern`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class UsingPattern {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        
        //Generate random color components:
        final Random rand = new Random();
        final byte[] components = new byte[3];
        rand.nextBytes(components);
        
        //Construct random color:
        final Color original = new Color(components[0] & 0xFF, components[1] & 0xFF, components[2] & 0xFF);
        
        //Debug:
        final String originalToString = original.toString();
        System.out.println(originalToString);
        
        //Parse:
        final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".+\\[r=(\\d{1,3})\\,g=(\\d{1,3}),b=(\\d{1,3})\\]").matcher(originalToString);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            final int r, g, b;
            System.out.println(r = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
            System.out.println(g = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2)));
            System.out.println(b = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3)));
            
            //Verify:
            System.out.println(new Color(r, g, b).equals(original));
        }
    }
}
```

### Notes:

- With this default `String` representation of a `Color`, you are asking for, you inherently lose the `ColorSpace` information as well as the `alpha` component.
- But you have other ways of properly encoding your `Color` and `ColorSpace` instances, such as:

  1. They are both `Serializable`.
  2. They may also be valid *JavaBeans* (at least `Color` seems to be so as stated in a [related official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/quick/button.html), while the `ColorSpace` is included into `Color`).
  3. `Color` seems to include all its components in its [value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB--) (for the default *sRGB* `ColorModel`), while the `ColorSpace` seems to be identifyable by its [type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.html#getType--).